# Error 12600: Authorization Denied with Netbanx payment iframe

Tags: netbanx-api, paysafe

TL;DR : I am getting a "12600: Authorisation Denied (12600)" error and can't find what that means in Netbanx/Paysafe's documentation.

Background:

I am using the Netbanx credit card services.
The request is built server-side to obtain a url, which is then embedded in an iframe on the application for clients to pay.
It works like a charm in test mode; the iframe displays Netbanx' form, the client enters their info, clicks "Pay", and the payment is authorized.  So far so good.

Now, I've moved to live mode.  Configurations (account numbers, API key and API secret) are all valid and used on other projects.  The payment request is still correctly built, I obtain a url from Netbanx and it correctly displays the payment form.  I enter valid credit card information, click pay, and then, boom: failure page, with error 12600: Authorization denied.  I cannot find any info related to that error code.  Has this occured to anyone?  What does this code mean?  Any details would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue here relates to Paysafe test API credentials being used on the production environment. These credentials do not translate from test > production as a separate set would need to be used for security reasons.

If you believe that you are ready to go live, you can login to the BackOffice "https://login.test.netbanx.com/" and click the "Go Live" button to start the process!